# New Zealand Projection System

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, new-zealand

I have a database with Easting and Northing points of New Zealand. The data structure is as follows

Easting  |   Northing

2595425  |   6622565

2594585  |   6622595

2595000  |   6622085

2594500  |   6622005

2595300  |   6622915

I need to create shapefile from this data. My Final goal is to convert this data to WGS84 system.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know which [UTM zone](http://gpsinformation.net/utm-zones.gif) your data is in.  New Zealand spans about three.  Once you know that, you follow [these steps](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) to create points.

Next, you'll want to [reproject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/) your data to WGS84.  You can specify your output shapefile here.

This is all you really need to do.  However, if you want your points to contain the longitude/latitude coordinates in WGS84 in the attributes, you'll need to [create two fields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000v000000) to store the information.  Then, right click on the fields in the attribute table and choose "[Calculate Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000027000000)" to calculate the X/Y coordinates.

Comment: New Zealand also has a couple of local coordinate systems. So you have to find out which CRS is actually used.

Comment: If the posted data's somewhere around Pakotai aka north central area of the North Island, it's using New Zealand Map Grid (based on NZ 1949). The easting values are too large for a UTM zone, or even NZTM (based on NZGD2000).